# How can I tell if Deserialization failed in protobuf.net?

Tags: deserialization, protobuf-net, data-integrity

I had protobuf.net deserialize invalid (random) bytes into a KeyValuePair (i.e. not nullable). Instead of (as expected) an exception being thrown, an empty struct was returned.

Since this default struct could be valid data, I don't see a way to tell if the source data are actually valid. Is this a bug, or is there a way I'm missing?

(protobuf-net 2.0.0.480, 2011.12.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

There were scenarios in v2 where it wouldn't spot this, but would instead terminate as though it had reached the end of the stream - in particular if the "field number", after applying shifts, was non-positive. However, this is **not** valid in a protobuf stream, and this will be fixed next build.

---

That depends on quite how random it was ;p Actually, getting that to do anything without throwing an error is pretty impressive - the protobuf spec is pretty specific about layout, and normally it **will** throw a big exception there (probably mentioning "unexpected wire-type" or similar).

Emphasis: in almost all cases it will throw an exception. If you fluke some data of the right spec, but different field numbers, then it will silently ignore the unexpected data, and you'll get an all-zero struct. If you fluke some data of the right spec, but with the right field numbers and layout, you'll get garbage. But that is like saying

> if I randomly generate data that by pure chance happens to be `{"foo":"0"}`, `JavascriptSerializer` doesn't complain!!! bug!!!

Are you *sure* you actually deserialized some data here? and that the stream wasn't already the EOF position? For example, the following won't error, as you haven't rewound the stream - you are effective deserializing zero bytes:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(randomBytes, 0, randomBytes.Length);
var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<Foo>(ms);
```

(and zero bytes is perfectly valid for a protobuf object)

If you want to test a stream for validity, you can use `ProtoReader`, just skipping (`SkipField()` or something similar) every field until `ReadNextHeader()` (or whatever) returns a non-positive integer.

Comment: The "random" input in this case was an XML file so I'd assume it should be very invalid. I'll check it again though, it would be very weird if it didn't throw an exception if it's supposed to.

Comment: @mafutrct did you manage to repro? I'd be very interested in an example if you did

Comment: I played around with it a bit more and apparently deserialization never throws for me, as long as the input is long enough. It simply returns defaults.

Comment: @mafutrct that sounds very contrary to everything I've seen; do you have any concrete examples?

Comment: Tried it with a fresh install of VS'10 on a different machine, too, same result. I used the protobuf-net.dll as input for deserialization.

Comment: @mafutrct that is ... unexpected ... investigating.

Comment: Oh, excellent edit. Thanks for your help, looking forward to the next release.